# numpy tolist() uncomfortable output

Tags: python, list, numpy, tolist

I'm trying to extract a column of a numpy matrix in a list form. I've used the method `tolist()`, but it is not useful for my purpose.
Let see the code.

```
import numpy as np
def get_values(feature):
    '''
    This method creates a lst of all values in a feature, without repetitions
    :param feature: the feature of which we want to extract values
    :return: lst of the values
    '''
    values = []
    for i in feature:
        if i not in values:
            values.append(i)
    return values
lst=[1, 2, 4, 4, 6]
a=get_values(lst)
print(a)
b=np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
col = b[:,0].tolist()
print(col)
if col == [1, 3]:
    print('done!')
```

OUTPUT

```
[1, 2, 4, 6]
[[1], [3]]
```

As you can see, the returned list from method `tolist()` is ignored in the if statement. Now, if I can't change the if statement (for any reason) how can I do to manage the `b` as if it were a list like `a`?

Comment: As an aside, your `get_values` function will scale horrifically with large `features`.

Comment: What do you mean for horribly? I had no problem with this function

Comment: @Well, then, features isn't very big. But your algorithm is quadratic time. If you use a `set`, it would be linear. If it works fine at the scales you are using it, then no need to change it. But be aware it is quadratic time.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis :) I've tried it with features of over 4000 rows, no problem seemed at horizon, but I agree with you

Comment: yeah, the differnces probably wouldn't show up until you are working with millions of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `numpy.matrix` objects always maintain two dimensions. Convert to array, then flatten:

```
>>> col = b[:,0].getA().flatten().tolist()
>>> col
[1, 3]
```

Or maybe just work with normal `numpy.ndarray`s...

```
>>> a = b.getA()
>>> a[:,0]
array([1, 3])
```

vs...

```
>>> b[:,0]
matrix([[1],
        [3]])
```